# C# Debugging: magical System Clock restore

Tags: c#, debugging, time

The program I am working on is used to test operations in a time-based schedule. As such, one of the requirements is to change the system clock to provoke another application into firing events. This is simple enough. My program runs a script, which can set the clock. When the script starts, I store the DateTime.Now and create a Stopwatch. When the script ends, if it has modified the system clock I read the elapsed time, add it to my start time, and set the system clock that value. All fine so far. HOWEVER. If I debug my program and stop it before the script ends, that restore never happens. I was wondering if there was any way to get the C# debugger to forcibly call some piece of code (or perform some action such as reading the time from an NIST server) when it shuts down?

Comment: A bit more digging has shown there's an event Application.ApplicationExit which can have handlers attached. Any idea if this will be called when terminating a debug session?

Answer (score 1):

Stopping the debugger is the same as terminating the process, so there is no guarantee, what is happening.
Nevertheless consider to implement a dispose or a finalize method.

Answer (score 1):

> "I debug my program and stop it..."

So you're wondering why your program doesn't continue after you've stopped it?

You can debug your program and then simply *detach* the debugger when you're done - this will leave the program running.

Comment: No, I understand perfectly well why my program shuts down :-) I want to avoid the continual annoyance of having the wrong system time **if** it can be avoided.

There are two programs here - my script-runner, and the main application. It is the former I am interested in.